# Is reading a fantasy novel haram?

Tags: halal-haram

Assalam alaikum, I want to whether will it be right to read fantasy novel that has magic in it(know that the magic that is haram in islam is black magic and the magic that I am referring to is different)also it is conducted in a different world would it be alright to read.
It will be easy if you guys study the novel yourself, the novel name is,the beginning after the end.
Plz answer

Answer (score 2):

It is not permissible to read this kind of book that includes black magic, and has a different world. The reason is that it will teach you things that you are prohibited to know, and will make you love the magicians and it isn't allowed. So therefore it isn't permissible to read this book.

Comment: I think you did not read the question correctly